# Clojure avoid repetition on tests

Tags: clojure

In my tests I need repeat this a block of tests for each function. In this case I'm testing bad-request function, the things that need change between each test is the bad-request call, code, and error.

```
(deftest t-bad-request
      ...

    (testing "with data"
        (equal (merge error code message DATA) (bad-request MESSAGE DATA)))

    (testing "without message and with data"
        (equal (merge error code DATA) (bad-request nil, DATA))))
```

What is the "correct way" to resolve it in clojure? macros?

Comment: I do not see a good way of automating your example.  Sometimes it is better to be explicit.  While this has some repetition is is easier for a reader to understand than a complicated & tricky solution that saves a few characters but is 10x more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think macros is the way to do this in clojure. Taking your code and doing some liberal assumptions about `bad-request`, `error` and the other stuff, I made up the following example:

```
(require '[clojure.test :refer [deftest testing is]])

; dummy implementations, here will be your real bad-request & error
(defn bad-request [& more] more)
(def error {:status :error})

(defmacro deftest-request [name code message MESSAGE DATA & body]
  `(deftest ~name
     (testing "with data"
       (is (= (merge error ~code ~message ~DATA) (bad-request ~MESSAGE ~DATA))))

     (testing "with data"
       (is (= (merge error ~code ~message ~DATA) (bad-request ~MESSAGE ~DATA))))

     ~@body))

; Some messages will only be tested about bad requests
(deftest-request some-request-test
  {:code 401} {:message "hello"} "HELO" {:data "WORLD"})

; Other messages can have more tests at the end of a deftest-request
(deftest-request some-complex-request-test
  {:code 829} {:message "a-complex-message"} "IM COMPLEX" {:data "VERY COMPLEX"}

  (testing "request returns something interesting"
    (is (= "I'm cool" (run-request {:message "a-complex-message"})))))
```

`deftest-request` will run the two common bad-request tests, and any additional form passed to it.

Of course you should consider the tradeoffs of using this approach versus plain old tests... In most cases it's more clear to have plain old tests... But if you have a lot of similar tests and/or a complex test preparation, a macro can be of help.

A good example of applying this technique is in the [sqlingvo test suite](https://github.com/r0man/sqlingvo/blob/master/test/sqlingvo/core_test.clj#L14-L86)